# Confusion with post increment and logical operator?

Tags: c, logical-operators, arithmetic-expressions

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main()
    {
         int i=-1, j=-1, k=0, l=2,m;
         m = i++&&j++&&k++||l++;
         printf("%d%d%d%d%d", i, j, k, l, m);
    }
```

Output:

> 00131

I am confused how the expression is getting evaluated.

Comment: @user2864740: There is no UB here, read it more carefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple logical operators in one line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382271/multiple-logical-operators-in-one-line-of-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that really matters here is the `||`.  Since `l++` evaluates to the boolean `1` (true), the entire statement is true.  So `m` is 1, and the rest are just their original values plus one for the post increment after they are evaluated.

You're evaluating the boolean expression:

```
((-1 && -1) && 0) || 2
```

---

As an aside, your definition of `main` should be:

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: thanks for response this expression will be evaluated as (-1&&-1)&&(0||2)

Comment: @nitesh.kodle123: No.  `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so it's `((-1 && -1) && 0) || 2`

Comment: Thanks I got it.Can you suggest me link which explains precedence operator in c.

Comment: @nitesh.kodle123: What about that confuses you?

Comment: again one confusion postfix (++/--)has higher precedence than prefix(++/--) in the (article)[ en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence] it is given.I know prefix has higher precedence than postfix please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52718/discussion-between-nitesh-kodle123-and-ed-s)

Comment: @nitesh.kodle123: I don't believe that you do "know" that because it is wrong. Postfix has a higher precedence than prefix. That doesn't change the *semantics* of postfix v prefix, it simply defines the order of evaluation.  I'm sorry but I can't join chat right now

Answer (score 2):

I presume your question is about which increments will actually occur.

&& and || (logical and and logical or) are "short-circuit" operations. They evaluate only enough of their arguments to determine whether they're true or false. Effectively, `x && y` can be treated as `x ? y : 0` and `x || y` can be treated as `x ? 1 : y`

&& takes precedence over ||, so start by looking at `i++ && j++ && k++`. This starts by evaluating `i++`, returning `-1` and setting `i` to `0`. Since the returned value is true (nonzero), we continue by evaluating `j++`, which once again returns `-1` (true) and increments `j` to 0. We still haven't proven the value of the `&&`, so we evaluate `k++`, which returns `0` (false) and increments `k` to 1. That false gives us a final anded value of false.

Now we proceed to the ||. Effectively, you now have `false || l++`. The false is not enough to determine the result of the or, so we evaluate `l++`. That returns `2` (true), while setting `l` to `3`. That true forces the value of the `||`, and the final value of the expression, to be `true`.

Note that if `i`, `j`, or `k` had started as 0 (false), the later increments would not have occurred, since short-circuit evaluation would have decided they weren't needed in order to produce a result. **In general, mixing `&&` or `||` with side effects is a bad idea for exactly this reason** -- it produces logic that is needlessly hard to understand. The `?:` versions -- or a real `if/then/else` statement -- would make this interaction much, much clearer. You should understand how to read this sort of mess, because you will run into it in other programmers' C code -- but you should almost never write it. And if you must, you should document it to death. The sanity you save may be your own.

Answer (score 0):

use this rules:

i++ =post increments the value of i, k++ =post increments the value of k, l++ =post increments the value of l, j++ =post increments the value of j

&& - if values compared are both nonzero true(1) otherwise false(0)

|| - if values compared are both zero false(0) otherwise true(1)

then apply towards expression m (also read on operator precedence in c)